# Can I use l'Hopital for $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n) = 0$ where $a_n = \tan(n) (\frac{1}{e})^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Wolfram Alpha tells me that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \tan(n) = -\infty$ to $\infty$. Does it mean that the limit doesn't exist?
Furthermore can I use l'Hopital for the following limit:
$\lim_{n\to \infty}(a_n) = 0$ where
$a_n = \tan(n) (\frac{1}{e})^{n}$ ?

Comment: The limit of $\tan n$ does not exist.

Comment: The limit is $0$, as you can see in your previous question's answer, and using l'Hopital does not make any sense here.

Comment: @Crostul the question is whether this is possible.

Comment: @Symeof The answer is no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The limit doesn't exist.
This is what wolfram alpha's notation means. So this isn't possible to use l'Hopital.